# Point & Figure doesn't work on all charts

Tags: pine-script

PnF works on some charts. Not at all

```
//@version=4
study("PnF", overlay = true)
pnf_tickerid = pointfigure(syminfo.tickerid, "hl", "Traditional", 1, 3)
pnf_close = security(pnf_tickerid, timeframe.period, close)
plot(pnf_close)
```

For example:

BINANCE: BTCUSDT OK. works well

BINANCE: XRPUSDT not working. Does not plot

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from the [poinfigure()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_pointfigure) function in the reference manual:
*param (float) ATR Length if `style` is equal to 'ATR', or Box Size if `style` is equal to 'Traditional'.*

You set the boxsize to `1`, but `BINANCE:XRPUSDT` never moves that much.
When you set it to `0.00001`, it will draw something.

```
//@version=4
study("PnF", overlay = true)

pnf_tickerid = pointfigure(syminfo.tickerid, "hl", "Traditional", 0.00001, 3)
pnf_close = security(pnf_tickerid, timeframe.period, close)

plot(pnf_close)
```

To always get a correct box size, you should be able to use `syminfo.mintick` for that, but somehow that doesn't compile and gives an `Internal server pine compilation error`.
I think that might be a bug in Pine Script.

```
//@version=4
study("PnF", overlay = true)

pnf_tickerid = pointfigure(syminfo.tickerid, "hl", "Traditional", syminfo.mintick, 3)
pnf_close = security(pnf_tickerid, timeframe.period, close)

plot(pnf_close)
```

You could use a workaround like this:

```
//@version=4
study("PnF", overlay = true)

pnf_close = security(pointfigure(syminfo.tickerid, "hl", "Traditional", syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:XRPUSDT" ? 0.00001 : 1, 3), timeframe.period, close)

plot(pnf_close)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right

@LonesomeTheBlue posted a script using syminfo.mintick, and this was the solution
https://in.tradingview.com/script/wcl6LYEE-Point-and-Figure-PnF-Chart/

Thank you @bjorn-mistiaen